# Qt Creator 12.0.0 context menu covers almost all content

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, contextmenu

After Qt Creator was updated to version 12.0.0, new items were added to the context menu, and the following artifact appeared:

Context menu bug:

[image: context menu bug]

As you can see in the screenshot, the context menu now opens in full size, which covers all the content.

How do I return the scroll bars to their original size, or how do I delete a few items to make them normal?

I couldn't find anything in the settings that could solve the problem.

Comment: Have you considered submitting a report on https://bugreports.qt.io/? There's a dedicated combo for the project, which includes a Qt Creator item.

Comment: Please specify the environment

Answer (score -1):

My workaround:

Changing the resolution in the OS settings.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid workaround, especially for a development environment where different screen resolutions may be important for both testing and developing.